# Why should I sacrifice Bishop?

Tags: tactics

I had a game with a friend, I obviously lost, but now I don't understand why, while reviewing my game, the CPU suggest that at this point the best move is Bishop in b5.

If the Queen decides to take the Bishop, there is nothing taking the Queen back:

[image]

Even continuing the game from there against CPU, the CPU doesn't take Bishop in b5. I don't get why.

Comment: Even continuing the game from there against CPU, the CPU don't take Bishop in B5 :/. I don't get why

Comment: I ran this position on my machine just now, and on depth 30 Stockfish thinks that dxc5 is the best move in the position (score=-0.09). Furthermore, Stockfish considers Bb5 to be slightly worse (score=-0.33). While Bb5 may not be a blunder (black's queen is the only thing defending the bishop on d6), it is not clear that it must be the best move.

Answer (score 11):

When ... Qxb5 is played, **White can play Bxd6**. This is a great spot for the bishop, because now your opponent can't castle and your bishop is controlling some nice squares. If Black doesn't capture on b5, then he pretty much needs to move his queen, since you're threatening it with that bishop. Once he retreats, **you have another piece developed, while your opponent has wasted a move running away.**

Comment: True, but on the other hand, after Qxb5, Bxd6 white has weakened the light squares and cannot immediately castle either. Doesn't seem all that obvious to me that the position is better for white.

Answer (score 2):

Queen takes b5, Bishop takes d6

Comment: So I am getting a downvote for pointing out, without unnecessary verbosity, to the original poster that it is not a sacrifice. That's OK

Comment: I did not downvote, but this might have been better as a (very useful) comment. It does not completely answer the question (Why tBb5 is the best move?) though. At least to me it is not at all obvious why I should play Bb5 here.

Answer (score 2):

The only immediate advantage of Bb5 is that it develops a piece with a tempo, which is usually a good idea. I would say that both whites light square bishop and blacks dark square bishop are probably worth around the same.
At the moment it's going to take some tempos for the light square bishop to contest the diagonal with either moving the Nd2 away or Bb5 to a4 then c2.

Comment: What's the point of Bb5 after Qc7?

Comment: You've gained a tempo while developing a piece at the same time. Moving your pieces into a better position while gaining a tempo is always good.

Comment: Sure, but the position is semi-closed, considerations like these are - in my view - just a bit abstract... For example I don't see any big difference in the position, had White played simply Bxd6 and then Be2, rather than Bb5. White's advantage is, if any, just theoretical.